# opencv imshow with waitKey too slow on Mac OS X 10.10.2 (using c++)

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, imshow

I am using opencv c++ on Mac OS X 10.10.2 to process video frames and display them. The performance of imshow with waitKey to display the video is extremely slow.

I have the following code which displays HD (1920x1080) grayscale frames correctly, except that it runs about 10 times too slow (i.e. 2 to 3 frames per second instead of 30 frames per second).

```
          cv::Mat framebuf[TEST_COUNT];

    //--- Code here to allocate and fill the frame buffer with about 4 seconds of video. This part works correctly.

        //--- This loop runs too slow by factor of approximately 10x
    for (int f = 0; f < TEST_COUNT; f++)
    {
        cv::imshow(windowName, framebuf[f]);
        cv::waitKey(33);
    }
```

Can anyone suggest how to get real-time or near real-time performance from opencv imshow()? I have seen many posts that state that they are displaying video in real-time or even faster than real-time, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And if you reduce the resolution of the frame, will it be still slow? What is the config of your machine? What do you think might be the cause of your problem?

Comment: If you are using debug mode, try to use release mode - sometimes difference in speed is really big.

Comment: @cyriel, that was a good suggestion. I changed from debug to release, and it did improve the speed, but still not real-time. I am now getting about 10 frames per second instead of 30fps.

Comment: @HaDang, I reduced the frame size of the frames in the frame buffer from HD to 860x540 (0.5x, 0.5y) and I am now getting about 20fps, so still not quite real-time. My MacBook Air is 1.7GHz, 2 cores i7, 8GB DDR3, Intel HD Graphics 5000 1536MB, 500GB SSD.

Comment: What's the value of `TEST_COUNT`? I would suggest setting the delay to 1 ms, because a single sleep (or here `waitKey`) call will typically block for far longer than a millisecond.

Comment: What version of OpenCV are you using?

Comment: @cyriel, I am using opencv 2.4.9.

Comment: @Kornel. The value of TEST_COUNT is 240, and I have already tried waitKey(1). TEST_COUNT is just the video buffer size. I have used a number of different video buffer sizes from 60 to 500. It does not affect the playback speed. I have also tried just reading each frame from a video file and displaying it without any buffer at all. None of this makes any difference to the video playback speed. I can never get real-time performance. My next step is to try a completely different video library to isolate whether the problem is in opencv or the performance of my computer.

Comment: Since the OS has a minimum time between switching threads, the `waitKey` will not wait exactly `delay` ms, it will wait at least `delay` ms, depending on what else is running on your computer at that time, so `cv::waitKey(1)` will suspend the current thread around 4-5ms. In your case it is 240*(4-5ms) which is equal to 960-1200ms per loop. That's why your loop runs about 10x slower.

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong but for me the problem is not with your code, but with your os/configuration. I've written a small test:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from random import randrange
img = np.zeros((1920, 1080), dtype = np.uint8)
counter = 0
while counter < 1000:
    cv2.line(img, (randrange(0, 1920), randrange(0, 1080)), (randrange(0, 1920), randrange(0, 1080)), (randrange(0, 255)))
    cv2.imshow('test', img)
    temp = cv2.waitKey(1)
    counter += 1
    print counter
```

On my machine (Core 2 duo 2,6Ghz x64, 8gb ram, ssd) it took about 30 seconds for this test to complete. Run it and if you will get significantly bigger time than definitelly something is wrong with your laptop/opencv configuration/etc. I've used OpenCV 2.4.x on Mac OS X (it was 10.9 i think) and it was running fine. Reinstalling OpenCV is the most obvious solution which comes to my mind. When you remove OpenCV, use brew to install it again - `brew install opencv --with-tbb --with-python --with-ffpmeg` (or something similar - check using `brew options opencv`) should be fine. First options tells brew to build opencv with tbb(thread building block - library for multithreading, sometimes can significantly improve speed), second to install python wrappers, and the last one to install ffmpeg(handle codecs etc).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have reinstalled opencv with the parameters that you recommended. I am seeing video playback at about 1/2 real-time speed, so I am much closer to real-time than I was getting before. For the purpose, of my project, this is sufficient. I still don't know why it will not run in real-time, but I can't chase this down any further at this time. Thank you.

Comment: Promise not to laugh, but it turns out that my video source material is 60fps, not 30fps. I first I thought that that was why it was running slow, but Cyriel is still correct that my system is just too slow. It can actually play back correctly at 30fps, but it just can't seem to handle 60fps. I still don't really know why. Cyriel suggestion to reinstall was a good one, and it helped, but I am still not able to do full HD at 60fps playback. Looks like I may need a more powerful computer.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to reduce the input to the function wait key. Try using a lower number in the range of 2-5. It also depends on the other processes you have running simultaneously, try shutting down other processes and see if it improves

Comment: I have tried to lower waitKey down to 2ms, but it doesn't help at all. I will try shutting down other processes. I am still confused since many applications can display video in real-time, so this may be an opencv implementation performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own window to show the image. Add MyWindow.m MyWindow.h file to project.

MyWindow.h

```
#ifndef MY_WINDOW_H
#define MY_WINDOW_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    void* createNSWindow(int x, int y, int w, int h);
    void renderNSWindow(void* inwindow, void* data, int w, int h, int c);
    void processNSEvent();
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

usage, in main.cpp, do not forget waitKey

```
#include "MyWindow.h"

// need create a cv window and do nothing
cv::namedWindow("xxx", 1);

// create window
void* w = createNSWindow(0, 0, 0, 0);

// frame image
cv::Mat frameImage;

// render loop
renderNSWindow(w, frameImage.data, frameImage.cols, frameImage.rows, frameImage.channels());

// need waitKey to display window
processNSEvent();
```

implement, in MyWindow.m, **delete import "MyWindow.h"**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MyWindow : NSWindow
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSImageView *imgv;
@end

@implementation MyWindow
@end


static NSImage* _createNSImage(void* data, int w, int h, int c);

void* createNSWindow(int x, int y, int w, int h) {

    NSRect screenFrame = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
    NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(x, y, w, h);
    if (w == 0 || h == 0) {
        frame = screenFrame;
    }

    MyWindow* window  = [[MyWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame
                                                    styleMask:NSWindowStyleMaskBorderless
                                                      backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                                        defer:NO] ;


    //_initApp(window);

    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];
    window.titleVisibility = TRUE;
    window.styleMask = NSWindowStyleMaskResizable | NSWindowStyleMaskTitled |NSWindowStyleMaskFullSizeContentView;

    window.imgv = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
    [window.contentView addSubview:window.imgv];


    return (void*)CFBridgingRetain(window);
}


static NSImage* _createNSImage(void* data, int w, int h, int c) {

    size_t bufferLength = w * h * c;

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, bufferLength, NULL);
    size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
    size_t bitsPerPixel = c * bitsPerComponent;
    size_t bytesPerRow = c * w;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast;
    if (c < 4) {
        bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaNone;
        unsigned char* buf = data;
        for(int i = 0; i < w*h; i++) {
            unsigned char temp = buf[i*c];
            buf[i*c] = buf[i*c+c-1];
            buf[i*c+c-1] = temp;
        }
    }
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(w,
                                    h,
                                    bitsPerComponent,
                                    bitsPerPixel,
                                    bytesPerRow,
                                    colorSpaceRef,
                                    bitmapInfo,
                                    provider,   // data provider
                                    NULL,       // decode
                                    YES,        // should interpolate
                                    renderingIntent);

    NSImage* image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:iref size:NSMakeSize(w, h)];
    return image;
}

void renderNSWindow(void* inwindow, void* data, int w, int h, int c) {
    MyWindow* window = (__bridge MyWindow*)inwindow;

    window.imgv.image = _createNSImage(data, w, h, c);

}

void processNSEvent() {
    for (;;)
    {
        NSEvent* event = [NSApp nextEventMatchingMask:NSEventMaskAny
                                            untilDate:[NSDate distantPast]
                                               inMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                              dequeue:YES];
        if (event == nil)
            break;

        [NSApp sendEvent:event];
    }
}
```

other things, the waitKey now take about 20ms, you can do OpenCV in background thread, and show window in main thread. Also use processNSEvent instead of waitKey that only take about 10ms.

full source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>
#include "MyWindow.h"


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int opencvfunc(int argc, const char *argv[]);
bool newFrame = false;
cv::Mat back_frame;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    cv::namedWindow("render", 1);

    void* w = createNSWindow(0, 0, 0, 0);

    dispatch_queue_t opencvq = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0);
    dispatch_async(opencvq, ^{
        opencvfunc(argc, argv);
    });


    while(true) {
        usleep(3*1000);
        if(newFrame) {
            std::chrono::system_clock::time_point starttime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            renderNSWindow(w, back_frame.data, back_frame.cols, back_frame.rows, back_frame.channels());
            newFrame = false;
            //auto key = cv::waitKey(1);
            //if (key == 'q') {
            //    break;
            //}
            processNSEvent();
            std::chrono::system_clock::time_point endtime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            std::cout << "imshow:" << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(endtime-starttime).count()*1000 << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int opencvfunc(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    cv::VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        std::cout << "Couldn't open camera 0." << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    Mat frame, unmodified_frame;

    for (;;) {

        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        if (frame.empty()) { // stop if we're at the end of the video
            break;
        }


        //unmodified_frame = frame.clone();

        // ...

        back_frame = frame.clone();
        newFrame = true;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV 4 had resolved this issue, please update to new version.

One more thing, process video and show video in two thread.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


bool newFrame = false;
Mat back_frame;

int opencvmain(int argc, char** argv ) {

    // open camear
    cv::VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        std::cout << "Couldn't open camera 0." << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // define frame images
    cv::Mat frame;

    // frame loop
    for (;;) {

        // get video frame
        cap >> frame;
        if (frame.empty()) {
            break;
        }

        // render
        back_frame = frame.clone();
        newFrame = true;        
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv ) {


    namedWindow("video", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

    dispatch_queue_t opencvq = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
    dispatch_async(opencvq, ^{
        opencvmain(argc, argv);
    });


    while(true) {
        usleep(3*1000);
        if(newFrame) {                
            imshow("video", back_frame);
            auto key = cv::waitKey(1);
            if (key == ' ') {
                break;
            }
            newFrame = false;                
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```