# The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to work with opencv on mac for facial identification, but keep getting this error message:

```
The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with 
Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian,
install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure
script in function cvShowImage
```

I am using python on mac osx and installed opencv using pip. Does anyone have past experience with this error and if so, how did you fix it?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

img = cv2.imread('/william.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
    for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
        cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex, ey), (ex+ew, ey+eh), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: _... any ideas on how to fix this?_  (supposing _this_ is openCV can't open a window, i.e `imshow`) __Long way__: You should do what the error message says. The version you installed was compiled without support for what you're trying to do. You need to download the sources and compile it your self to fit your needs. It's a really simple process __once you understand what you are doing__ which is hard to achieve. You should give it a try if you really want to know OpenCV. __Short way__: as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28641569/7484570) suggests, you may tweak opencv installation on mac.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Verify a DIR where you install opencv lib-files

   ```
   print(cv2.getBuildInformation())
   ```
2. Recompilate it [via instruction on linux](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html) (or another at official site)
3. Copy files from recompilation dir "build/bin" to your DIR where your previous opencv.